# Книги по архитектуре, устройству памяти, процессору

Tags: linux, unix, ассемблер, книги, memory

Здравствуйте.
вот хочу прочитать что-то по устройству ПК. Нужна книга не про чистое железо или чистое программирование, а что-то среднее. В универе раньше учили ассемблер, но учили в основном для старых машин типа 8086. Сейчас уже все по-другому устроено. То есть знания есть, нужно просто обновить + выучить то, что появилось новое. Желательно, чтобы в качестве ОС была UNIX.
Основные моменты, которые хотел бы увидеть в книге:

1. Устройство самого компьютера (шины, взаимодействие процессора с памятью) в общих чертах.
2. Одно из самых главных - это устройство и размещение оперативной памяти. Модели памяти. Как располагается ядро в памяти, как запускаются программы, как размещены сегменты программ в виртуальном адресном пространстве и так далее.
3. Как взаимодействуют программы с процессором.
4. Как работает многопоточность на одноядерном и многоядерных процессорах.
5. Основы написания программ на ассемблере, только для современных архитектур процессоров.

То есть хотелось бы более детально изучить принцип взаимодействия различных модулей компьютера в операционных системах (желательно UNIX). Особенно интересна тема организации памяти и многопоточности. 
Кто-то, может, знает хорошую литературу по таким темам, не устаревшую. Желательно даже на английском (но необязательно). 
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классику смотрели? Тоненбаум - "Архитектура компьютера" и "Современные операционные системы". А вот по теории параллельных вычислений ничего не скажу, тема встречалась отрывками только. По ассемблер на WASM можно заглянуть.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел новые издания  на английском, почитаю обязательно.